# Get Last Unique Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I cant get my head around even attempting to write this query..

If I have a table called 'WaitTable' like so:

```
Id  StartTime           EndTime             ShopName        Request    WaitTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
1   2013-08-24 19:30    2013-08-24 19:45    ClothesShop1    1          10
2   2013-08-24 19:30    2013-08-24 19:45    ClothesShop1    2          15
3   2013-08-24 19:30    2013-08-24 19:45    ClothesShop1    3          3
4   2013-08-24 19:45    2013-08-24 20:00    ClothesShop1    1          12
5   2013-08-24 19:45    2013-08-24 20:00    ClothesShop1    2          17
```

I want to get all the last unique requests, to get their last recorded wait times.

So for example, I would want to return:

```
Id  StartTime           EndTime             ShopName        Request     WaitTime
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
3   2013-08-24 19:30    2013-08-24 19:45    ClothesShop1    3           3
4   2013-08-24 19:45    2013-08-24 20:00    ClothesShop1    1           12
5   2013-08-24 19:45    2013-08-24 20:00    ClothesShop1    2           17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with the `ROW_NUMBER()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Request ORDER BY Id DESC)'RowNum'
      FROM YourTable
      )sub
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7aa3d/1/0)

`PARTITION BY` defines the group which numbering will start over for. Ie, each value of `Request` will have numbering starting at 1 and going up.

`ORDER BY` defines how the `ROW_NUMBER()` will be ordered.

You might want to `ORDER BY StartTime DESC`, but that depends on your data.